# How to run a method simultaneously for each element in a List

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to call below `calculation()` simultaneously in `calculateKalmanValues()` for each element in the 'movingBeacons' list to reduce the processing time. I think java `stream.parallel()` is the ideal solution.

```
public void calculation(){
           // do some think
}
```

// This is the method which I call calculation()
//for each element in the  movingBeacons list simultaneously should called the calculation method

```
public void calculateKalmanValues()  {
       List<String> movingBeacons=incomingBtRssiRepository.movingBeacons();

       movingBeacons.forEach.parallel()
}
```

By using java stream.parallel() or multithreading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a parallel stream:

```
List<String> movingBeacons = incomingBtRssiRepository.movingBeacons();
movingBeacons.parallelStream()
    .forEach(s -> s.calculation());
```

But note that parallel streams might not always speed up serial operations.  See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) for caveats.